# Segmentation fault when I increase the size of vector in parallel merge sort

Tags: c++, c++11, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mergesort

When I try to run the program using 2 threads and a size of more than 4.5 million it creates a segmentation fault. Anything below that number runs smoothly. In short very large numbers generate a segfault and I don't know why. I would like to know if the error has to do with the thread creation or the distribution of work to the threads. Some help will be appreciated. Below is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

/* define variables for the problem */
#define UPPER_LIM 10
#define LOWER_LIM  1

using namespace std;

/* function definitions */

int generate_random_number(unsigned int lower_limit, unsigned int upper_limit);
void merge_sort(vector<int>& array, int left, int right);
void merge(vector<int>& array, int left, int middle, int right);
void thread_merge_sort(vector<int>& array, int thread_id, int n, int p, int q);
bool isTest_array_is_in_order(vector<int>& array, int LENGTH);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int NUM_THREADS = atoi(argv[1]);
    int LENGTH = atoi(argv[2]);
    int NUMBERS_PER_THREAD = LENGTH / NUM_THREADS;
    int OFFSET = LENGTH % NUM_THREADS;

    srand(time(0));

    std::vector<int> array;
    array.reserve(LENGTH);

    /* initialize array with random numbers */
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        array.push_back(generate_random_number(LOWER_LIM, UPPER_LIM));
    }

    /* begin timing */
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    const size_t nthreads = NUM_THREADS; //std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    {
        // Pre loop
        std::cout << "parallel(" << nthreads << " threads):" << std::endl;
        std::vector<std::thread> workers;

        for (std::size_t t = 0; t < nthreads; t++) {
            workers.push_back(thread(thread_merge_sort, ref(array), t, nthreads, NUMBERS_PER_THREAD, OFFSET));
        }

        for (thread& t: workers) { // await thread termination
            t.join();
        }
    }

    auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
    auto usec    = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count();

    // and print time
    std::cout << "Spent " << usec << " executing  " << nthreads << " in parallel " << " array size " << LENGTH << std::endl;

    /* end timing */

    /* test to ensure that the array is in sorted order */
    if (!isTest_array_is_in_order(array, LENGTH)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: array is not sorted!!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

/* generate random numbers within the specified limit */
int generate_random_number(unsigned int lower_limit, unsigned int upper_limit) {
    //srand(time(NULL));
    return lower_limit + (upper_limit - lower_limit) * ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX);
}

/** assigns work to each thread to perform merge sort */
void thread_merge_sort(vector<int> &arr, int thread_id, int NUM_THREADS, int NUMBERS_PER_THREAD, int OFFSET) {
    int left = thread_id * (NUMBERS_PER_THREAD);
    int right = (thread_id + 1) * (NUMBERS_PER_THREAD) - 1;
    if (thread_id == NUM_THREADS - 1) {
        right += OFFSET;
    }
    int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
    if (left < right) {
        merge_sort(arr, left, right);
        merge_sort(arr, left + 1, right);
        merge(arr, left, middle, right);
    }
}

/* test to ensure that the array is in sorted order */
bool isTest_array_is_in_order(vector<int>& arr, int LENGTH) {
    for (int i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= arr[i - 1]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

/* perform merge sort */
void merge_sort(vector<int>& arr, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        merge_sort(arr, left, middle);
        merge_sort(arr, middle + 1, right);
        merge(arr, left, middle, right);
    }
}

/* merge function */
void merge(vector<int>& arr, int left, int middle, int right) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int left_length = middle - left + 1;
    int right_length = right - middle;
    int left_array[left_length];
    int right_array[right_length];

    /* copy values to left array */
    for (int i = 0; i < left_length; i++) {
        left_array[i] = arr[left + i];
    }

    /* copy values to right array */
    for (int j = 0; j < right_length; j++) {
        right_array[j] = arr[middle + 1 + j];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    /** chose from right and left arrays and copy */
    while (i < left_length && j < right_length) {
        if (left_array[i] <= right_array[j]) {
            arr[left + k] = left_array[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[left + k] = right_array[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    /* copy the remaining values to the array */
    while (i < left_length) {
        arr[left + k] = left_array[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j < right_length) {
        arr[left + k] = right_array[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `merge_sort(arr, left, right); merge_sort(arr, left + 1, right);` doesn't make much sense. Shouldn't `middle` be used in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

So first, I stubbed your merge_sort and merge, run with 2 Tasks and 4500000 Elements: no segfault.

For complete debugging you might consider to provide the full code...

here my compiling, slightly modified code:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <vector>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdint>
    #include <algorithm>

    #include <thread>

    /* define variables for the problem */
    constexpr size_t const UPPER_LIM = 10;
    constexpr size_t const LOWER_LIM =  1;

    using namespace std;

    /* function definitions */

    void merge_sort(vector<int>& array, int left, int right){
      return;
    }

    void merge(vector<int>& array, int left, int middle, int right){
      return;
    }

    bool isTest_array_is_in_order(vector<int>& array, int LENGTH){
      return false;
    }

    /**
     * generate random numbers within the specified limit
     */
    int generate_random_number(unsigned int lower_limit, unsigned int upper_limit){
      return lower_limit + (upper_limit - lower_limit) * ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX);
    }

    /**
     * assigns work to each thread to perform merge sort
     */
    void thread_merge_sort(vector<int> &arr, int thread_id, int NUM_THREADS, int NUMBERS_PER_THREAD, int OFFSET){
      int left = thread_id * (NUMBERS_PER_THREAD);
      int right = (thread_id + 1) * (NUMBERS_PER_THREAD) - 1;
      if (thread_id == NUM_THREADS - 1) {
        right += OFFSET;
      }
      int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
      if (left < right) {
        merge_sort(arr, left, right);
        merge_sort(arr, left + 1, right);
        merge(arr, left, middle, right);
      }
    }

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

      int const NUM_THREADS        = 2; //atoi (argv[1]);
      int const LENGTH             = 4500000; //atoi(argv[2]);
      int const NUMBERS_PER_THREAD = LENGTH / NUM_THREADS;
      int const OFFSET             = LENGTH % NUM_THREADS;

      cout << sizeof(int) << "\n";

      srand(time(0)) ;

      std::vector<int> array;
      array.reserve(LENGTH);

      /* initialize array with random numbers */
      for(int ii=0; ii < LENGTH; ++ii){
        array.push_back(generate_random_number(LOWER_LIM, UPPER_LIM));
      }

      /* begin timing */
      auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

      const size_t nthreads = NUM_THREADS; //std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
      {
        // Pre loop
        std::cout<<"parallel ("<<nthreads<<" threads):"<<std::endl;
        std::vector<std::thread> workers;

        for(std::size_t tt=0; tt<nthreads; ++tt){
          workers.push_back(thread(thread_merge_sort, ref(array), tt, nthreads, NUMBERS_PER_THREAD, OFFSET));
        }

        // await thread termination
        for(thread& t: workers) {
          t.join();
        }
      }

      auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
      auto usec    = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count();

      // and print time
      std::cout << "Spent " << usec << " executing  " << nthreads << " in parallel " << " array size " << array.size() << "\n";

      /* end timing */
      return 0;
    }
```

[Edit]:

Your isTest_array_is_in_order can not work, as you return just after the first two elements are compared.

```cpp
    bool isTest_array_is_in_order(vector<int>& arr, int LENGTH)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<LENGTH;i++){
            if(arr[i]>=arr[i-1]){
                return true;
    }   else{

        return false;
        }

        }
    }
```

here is a version that shoud work:

```cpp
    /**
     * test to ensure that the array is in sorted order
     */
    bool isTest_array_is_in_order(vector<int>& arr, int LENGTH){
      bool unorderd = false;
      for(int ii=1;ii<LENGTH;++ii){
        if(arr[ii]<arr[ii-1]){
          unorderd = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      return !unorderd;
    }
```

[Edit]:

So at first with your code I was able to confirm your segfaults

I changed the code, and now it seems to run pretty fine
just tested 16 threads for 44999999 Elements, works nicely

After looking at your code, it crashed right here:

```cpp
    /* merge function */
    void merge(vector<int>& arr, int left, int middle, int right) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int left_length = middle - left + 1;
        int right_length = right - middle;
        int left_array[left_length];
        int right_array[right_length];
```

Here you create 2 local arrays, but on Stack, not on the Heap.
Stack is normally limited depending on your OS to some low MB like 10 or so.

So I replaced your C-Arrays with vectors and optimized the Code a bit further: more elaborate types, changed the main, so I can now sort different randomized variations with one run.

so here is my code now:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

using idx_t  = size_t;
using data_t = int;

/* define variables for the problem */
constexpr data_t const UPPER_LIM =  2000000;
constexpr data_t const LOWER_LIM = 0;

constexpr idx_t const REPEAT_CNT = 10000;

/* function definitions */
std::string to_array_str(vector<data_t>& arr, idx_t max_elem){
  std::stringstream ss;

  idx_t ii=1;
  idx_t cnt = 0;

  for(auto _d:arr){
    ss << setw(8) << _d;
    if(0==(ii%10)){
      ss << ",\n";
      ii=0;
    }else{
      ss << ", ";
    }
    if(cnt>=max_elem) break;
    ++ii;
    ++cnt;
  }
  return ss.str();
}

/**
 * generate random numbers within the specified limit
 */
data_t generate_random_number(data_t const lower_limit, data_t const upper_limit){
  static std::random_device rd;
  static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<data_t> dis(lower_limit, upper_limit);
  return dis(gen);
  //return lower_limit + (upper_limit - lower_limit) * ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX);
}

/**
 * test to ensure that the array is in sorted order
 */
bool isTest_array_is_in_order(vector<data_t>& arr){
  bool unorderd = false;
  for(idx_t ii=1;ii<arr.size();++ii){
    if(arr[ii]<arr[ii-1]){
      unorderd = true;
      cout << "unordered Index: " << ii << "\n";
      cout << "arr[ii] " << arr[ii] << " arr[ii-1] " << arr[ii-1] << "\n";

      break;
    }
  }
  return !unorderd;
}

/**
 * merge function
 */
void merge(vector<data_t>& arr, idx_t const left, idx_t const middle, idx_t const right) {
  idx_t const  left_length = middle - left + 1;
  idx_t const right_length = right - middle;
  vector<data_t>  left_array( left_length);
  vector<data_t> right_array(right_length);

  constexpr bool const use_loopcopy = true;
  if(use_loopcopy){
  /* copy values to left array */
  for(idx_t ii=0; ii < left_length; ++ii){
      left_array[ii] = arr[left + ii];
  }
  /* copy values to right array */
  for(idx_t ii=0; ii < right_length; ++ii){
    right_array[ii] = arr[middle + 1 + ii];
  }
  }

  constexpr bool const use_libcode = false;
  if(use_libcode){
  {
    auto from =  arr.begin();
    auto to   = from;
    std::advance(from,left);
    std::advance(to,middle+1);
    std::copy(from,to,left_array.begin());
  }
  {
    auto from = arr.begin();
    auto to   = from;
    std::advance(from,middle+1);
    std::advance(to,right+1);
    std::copy(from,to,right_array.begin());
  }
  }

  idx_t ii = 0;
  idx_t jj = 0;
  idx_t kk = 0;
  /** chose from right and left arrays and copy */
  while((ii < left_length) && (jj < right_length)){
    if(left_array[ii] <= right_array[jj]){
      arr[left + kk] = left_array[ii];
      ++ii;
    } else {
      arr[left + kk] = right_array[jj];
      ++jj;
    }
    ++kk;
  }

  /* copy the remaining values to the array */
  while(ii < left_length){
    arr[left + kk] = left_array[ii];
    ++kk;
    ++ii;
  }

  while(jj < right_length){
    arr[left + kk] = right_array[jj];
    ++kk;
    ++jj;
  }
  return;
}

/**
 * perform merge sort
 */
void merge_sort(vector<data_t>& arr, idx_t const left, idx_t const right) {
  if(left < right){
    idx_t middle = left + ((right - left)>>1);
    //Divide
    merge_sort(arr, left, middle);
    merge_sort(arr, middle + 1, right);
    //Conquer
    merge(arr, left, middle, right);
  }
  return;
}

/**
 * assigns work to each thread to perform merge sort
 */
void thread_merge_sort(vector<data_t>& arr, idx_t const thread_id, idx_t const NUM_THREADS, idx_t const NUMBERS_PER_THREAD, idx_t const OFFSET){
  idx_t left  =  thread_id * (NUMBERS_PER_THREAD);
  idx_t right = (thread_id + 1) * (NUMBERS_PER_THREAD) - 1;
  if(thread_id == (NUM_THREADS - 1)) {
    right += OFFSET;
  }
  merge_sort(arr,left,right);
  return;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

  /*
  int const NUM_THREADS        = 16; //atoi (argv[1]);
  int const LENGTH             = 1000000000; //atoi(argv[2]);
  */
  /*
  int const NUM_THREADS        = 8; //atoi (argv[1]);
  int const LENGTH             = 449999; //atoi(argv[2]);
  */
  int const NUM_THREADS        = 8; //atoi (argv[1]);
  int const LENGTH             = 100; //atoi(argv[2])

  int const NUMBERS_PER_THREAD = LENGTH / NUM_THREADS;
  int const OFFSET             = LENGTH % NUM_THREADS;

  cout << sizeof(int) << "\n";

  //srand(time(0)) ;

  std::vector<int> array(LENGTH);
  //array.reserve(LENGTH);

  constexpr size_t  nthreads = NUM_THREADS; //std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  std::cout<<"parallel ("<<nthreads<<" threads):"<<std::endl;


  uint64_t time = 0;
  bool ordered = true;
  for(idx_t ii=0; ii<REPEAT_CNT; ++ii){

    /* initialize array with random numbers */
    for(int ii=0; ii < LENGTH; ++ii){
      //array.push_back(generate_random_number(LOWER_LIM, UPPER_LIM));
      array[ii]=(generate_random_number(LOWER_LIM, UPPER_LIM));
    }

    /* begin timing */
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    {
      // Pre loop
      std::vector<std::thread> workers;

      for(std::size_t tt=0; tt<nthreads; ++tt){
        workers.push_back(thread(thread_merge_sort, ref(array), tt, nthreads, NUMBERS_PER_THREAD, OFFSET));
      }

      // await thread termination
      for(thread& t: workers) {
        t.join();
      }

      ordered &= isTest_array_is_in_order(array);
      if(!ordered) break;
    }

      auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
      auto usec    = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count();
      time = (usec + time)>>1;
  }

  // and print time
  //cout << "Spent " << usec << "[µs] executing " << nthreads << " Threads in parallel working on " << array.size() << " elements " << "\n";
  cout << "Spent " << time << "[µs] executing " << nthreads << " Threads in parallel working on " << array.size() << " elements " << "\n";

  //cout << "Result is ordered: " << isTest_array_is_in_order(array) << "\n";
  cout << "Result is ordered: " << ordered << "\n";

  cout << to_array_str(array,100) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

But even if that code now does not cause segfaults any more, playing around with different parameters, it turns out, that
It harldy ever produces a sorted array, except for single Thread runs.
So the analysis of chqrlie is correct as the sorted parts of single threads also need to be sorted.

Comment: I just edited in the whole code. the size and number of thread used isnt constant but given by the user. this is because i'm calculating the performance with different sizes and different number of threads. Your code makes 4.5mil constant but i'm trying to run in greater numbers and thats where i get problems

Comment: I know, I just did it constant for quick testing... it's way faster this way, than editing comandline parameters in some IDE Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in `merge`, you allocate the subarrays with automatic storage with a combined size equal to that of the slice to sort, causing a **stack overflow** for large arrays.
- the function `isTest_array_is_in_order` only compares the first 2 elements of the array.
- splitting the array into N slices to sort individually will only do that: sort portions of the array. You need a final phase where you merge the slices into a totally sorted array.
- the thread function `thread_merge_sort` should just call `merge_sort()` on its slice:

  ```
  /** assigns work to each thread to perform merge sort */
  void thread_merge_sort(vector<int> &arr, int thread_id, int NUM_THREADS, int NUMBERS_PER_THREAD, int OFFSET) {
      int left = thread_id * NUMBERS_PER_THREAD;
      int right = left + NUMBERS_PER_THREAD - 1;
      if (thread_id == NUM_THREADS - 1) {
          right += OFFSET;
      }
      merge_sort(arr, left, right);
  }
  ```
- specifying the slices with `left` and `right` included is error prone: you must adjust the lengths cautiously, whereas if `right` was excluded, the code is much more regular as the length can be computed directly as `right - left`.
- the slice boundaries and the index variables should be typed as `size_t` rather than `int`.

Here is a modified version that uses vectors for the temporary copies:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

/* generate random numbers in the range 1..9 */
#define LOWER_LIM  1
#define UPPER_LIM 10

using namespace std;

/* function declarations */
int generate_random_number(unsigned int lower_limit, unsigned int upper_limit);
void merge_sort(vector<int>& array, size_t start, size_t end);
void merge(vector<int>& array, size_t start, size_t middle, size_t end);
void thread_merge_sort(vector<int>& array, size_t start, size_t end);
bool is_vector_sorted(vector<int>& array, size_t length);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    const size_t NUM_THREADS = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 1;
    const size_t LENGTH = argc > 2 ? strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0) : 1000;

    std::vector<int> array(LENGTH);

    /* initialize array with random numbers */
    srand(time(0));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        array[i] = generate_random_number(LOWER_LIM, UPPER_LIM);
    }

    const size_t nthreads = NUM_THREADS; //std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    const size_t NUMBERS_PER_THREAD = LENGTH / nthreads;
    const size_t REMAINDER = LENGTH % nthreads;

    /* Output message before the loop */
    std::cout << "Sorting " << LENGTH << " elements in parallel" <<
        " using " << nthreads << " threads:" << std::endl;

    /* begin timing */
    auto start_clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    for (size_t t = 0; t < nthreads; t++) {
        size_t start = t * NUMBERS_PER_THREAD;
        size_t end = start + NUMBERS_PER_THREAD;
        if (t == nthreads - 1)
            end += REMAINDER;
        workers.push_back(thread(thread_merge_sort, ref(array), start, end));
    }
    /* await thread termination */
    for (thread& t: workers) {
        t.join();
    }
    /* merge thread slices */
    for (size_t size = NUMBERS_PER_THREAD; size < LENGTH; size += size) {
        for (size_t middle = size; middle < LENGTH; middle += size + size) {
            size_t end = min(middle + size, LENGTH);
            merge(array, middle - size, middle, end);
        }
    }

    /* end timing */
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_clock;
    auto usec    = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count();

    /* print time */
    std::cout << "Sorting time: " << usec << " microseconds." << std::endl;

    /* test to ensure that the array is in sorted order */
    if (!is_vector_sorted(array, LENGTH)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: array is not sorted!!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

/* generate random numbers within the specified limit */
int generate_random_number(unsigned int lower_limit, unsigned int upper_limit) {
    return int(lower_limit + double(upper_limit - lower_limit) * rand() / RAND_MAX);
}

/** assign work to each thread to perform merge sort */
void thread_merge_sort(vector<int> &arr, size_t start, size_t end) {
    merge_sort(arr, start, end);
}

/* test to ensure that the array is in sorted order */
bool is_vector_sorted(vector<int>& arr, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/* perform merge sort */
void merge_sort(vector<int>& arr, size_t start, size_t end) {
    if (end - start >= 2) {
        size_t middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
        merge_sort(arr, start, middle);
        merge_sort(arr, middle, end);
        merge(arr, start, middle, end);
    }
}

/* merge function */
void merge(vector<int>& arr, size_t start, size_t middle, size_t end) {
    size_t i, j, k;
    size_t left_length = middle - start;
    size_t right_length = end - middle;
    vector<int> left_array(&arr[start], &arr[middle]);
    vector<int> right_array(&arr[middle], &arr[end]);

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = start;
    /** chose from right and left arrays and copy */
    while (i < left_length && j < right_length) {
        if (left_array[i] <= right_array[j]) {
            arr[k++] = left_array[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = right_array[j++];
        }
    }
    /* copy the remaining values to the array */
    while (i < left_length) {
        arr[k++] = left_array[i++];
    }
    while (j < right_length) {
        arr[k++] = right_array[j++];
    }
}
```

The performance can be further improved by about 40% by saving only the left portion of the slice in `merge`: the elements of the right part of the slice are not overwritten unless they have already been copied. Here is a modified version:

```cpp
/* merge function */
void merge(vector<int>& arr, size_t start, size_t middle, size_t end) {
    size_t i, j, k;
    size_t left_length = middle - start;
    /* save the left part of the slice */
    vector<int> left_array(&arr[start], &arr[middle]);

    i = 0;
    j = middle;
    k = start;
    /** chose from right and left arrays and copy */
    while (i < left_length && j < end) {
        if (left_array[i] <= arr[j]) {
            arr[k++] = left_array[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    /* copy the remaining values to the array */
    while (i < left_length) {
        arr[k++] = left_array[i++];
    }
}
```